# Why event listeners not working on Nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, frontend, listener

Hoping to get some help here, excuse me if i'm missing something completely obvious, i'm still learning NextJS.

I'm working on an app for microservices as part of the freeCodeCamp course, and for some reason my `onClick` , `onSubmit` etc.. listeners don't work. I am using the new experimental version on Next, so i'm wondering if that is the issue or something else.

You can find all my files here and test it yourself:
https://github.com/vkats90/nextjs-13-api.git

Here is the front page (app/page.jsx) with a simple button with a listener I put there to test if it's listening, and it's not:

```
'use client'

import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log('hello');
}

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          freeCodeCamp API exercise
        </h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          Choose any of the following Microservices:
        </p>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a href="/timestamp-microservice" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>Timestamp &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Get the time in UTC and Unix</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="/header-parser-microservice"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Headparser &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Get you client and IP information</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="/url-shortener-microservice"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Url Shortener &rarr;</h2>
            <p>input your url and get a shorter one</p>
          </a>
          <a
            href="/exercise-tracker"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Exercise Tracker &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Log in and track your exercises</p>
          </a>
          <a
            href="/filemetadata-microservice"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>File Metadata &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Upload a file and get information about it</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://github.com/vkats90"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Made by Vlad Kats
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi v.kats
1- do you have any error in your code editor(related to eslint ,...) or in your console?
2- try to change on click code to `onClick={()=>handleClick()}`. maybe it works for you.

Comment: Hi Ali, I figured out the problem, partly. I kept expecting to see the console log on the vs code terminal rather than the actual browser console, and the responses weren't coming. I saw the logs on the console, it works fine, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

The listeners were working, I just wasn't looking in the right spot for the logs. should have been looking in the browser console rather than the vs code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved the problem or not. But to answer your question, **by default**, NextJS use **Server Component** which means that event listener **can not** work since the component is rendered on the server side so the user can not interact with our component much (**this is one of the difference between Server Component and SSR**)

In order to handle this issue, we can switch to using client components by typing `"use client"` at the top of your component file.

You can refer to this link to see the comparisons between Server and Client component

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components